# How to calculates how many boxes?

Tags: java

anyone git a hit for this question?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skj9n.png)

I am thinking about using the remaining and identity the rest to add the donut boxes.

Comment: Please, put code directly in your question, don't use screenshots like this. It will be more clarity for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the number of donuts by 12, and the result would give you the minimum amount of boxes you need for the order. Of course, if the number of donuts is less than 12, a simple division would return 0, but you need at least 1 box, so you might want to take the `Math.ceil()` of the division. Doing this would return a 1 when the number of donuts is less than 12.

Something like:

```
public static int calculateBoxes(int numDonuts) {
    return Math.ceil(numDonuts / 12);
}
```

Do not forget to import Math if you haven't already!

A problem arises when the number of donuts is 0. I don't know if your code allows it, but you might want to consider throwing an exception or some other error to deal with the issue.

Comment: thank you so much it helps !